# Featured tab not displaying the number of questions next to it when looking at questions for more than one tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, bounties

I pay attention to a group of tags by looking at the following URL:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs+or+elisp+or+emacs-lisp+or+dot-emacs

That works fine, and when you click on the 'Featured' tab, you get a list of the items featured.  However, the (non-zero) number of featured questions does not show up in the original page (the URL above), whereas if you look at only a single tag, you *do* get the non-zero number of featured questions next to the featured tab.

This is the case whether you `or` or `and` the tags together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it happens, the "featured" tab has *worked* for composite tags for a considerable time, which you can see by visiting tabs in a particular order, for example:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request?sort=featured
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+or+support

this is actually now showing you the featured *questions* for either tag, but the tab-header is conspicuously absent. However, starting from the next deploy, the "featured" tab works *fully* (including the tab-header / count) in all scenarios. Enjoy.